# How to pass input filed value using php class and function method

Tags: php

I am making admin panel and need to pass a input filed data using php class method like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" onchange="<?php $UpdateObj->SetTitle(); ?>" placeholder="Enter title">
```

can anyone tell how is it possible. So on change value get to DB.

Comment: Is there any one to help me out in this.

Comment: `<?php $UpdateObj->SetTitle(); ?>` is echoing a string or returning it? If it returns a string you must do this: `<?php echo $UpdateObj->SetTitle(); ?>`

Comment: `onchange` attribute will accept only javascript functions not PHP functions

Comment: Thanks, but i need to send this field value to database as onchange.

Comment: You need to do it via AJAX. Your AJAX script should catch your `onchange` event and accordingly it should request to the PHP function which does the DB updation. Have a look at http://phppot.com/jquery/ajax-add-edit-delete-records-in-database-using-php-and-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

> can anyone tell how is it possible.

It's not.

You can't mix HTML (`<input>`) or JavaScript (`onchange="..."`) with PHP (`<?php ... ?>`).

Either use [`AJAX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) (which is what you actually want), or use `SetTitle()` method after submitting the form (which is what you do not want).

Also, learn on basics about HTTP protocol and life of requests, it might give you a hint when is `PHP` turn, and when is the `HTML` turn.